# How do I get the text decoding of the Chinese?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, python-requests

Python in the Chinese part of the result of requests.get (url) is

"æ ?? ¯ä¸? Ç§? Å? ¯ä» ¥ è ?? ªç? ± å? ¼å? ¸ç? ??? Æ ???? è§? ï¼ "

came out in this way.

How it is necessary to decode Can you print Chinese characters?

In the following method, source and other statements will be output.

1. result.content.decode("gbk","ignore").encode("utf-8","ignore")
2. content.encode('utf-8').decode('gbk')

Example of a site is here. https://lvyou.baidu.com/notes/20fd27d671563fe1e8927d21?sid=9739db6e97289b7e6b22f9ea?request_id=831992042&idx=0

Let us know would really appreciate.

Comment: What happens when you just `print(result.content)`? The data is utf-8 encoded.

Comment: <Div class = "content"> is the address of the sample as a result of encoding the front. original : 第一次带着婆婆妈妈一起全家旅行，起初做攻略的时候还是很忐忑的

Comment: The result of the encoding method in 1. 绗涓娆″甫鐫濠嗗﹩濡堝堜竴璧峰叏瀹舵梾琛岋紝璧

Comment: The result of the encoding method in 2. 
莽卢卢盲赂聙忙卢隆氓赂娄莽聺聙氓漏聠氓漏聠氓娄聢氓娄聢盲

Comment: What is wrong with the content you get back?

Comment: original text is the result of a wish to me, it was to resolve the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved.

Set the encoding option in requests, we were able to obtain the required value.

Thank you very much.

```
sub_result = requests.get(sub_url)
sub_result.encoding = 'utf-8'
sub_soup = BeautifulSoup(sub_result.text, 'lxml')
```